# Progress bar function constantly show 0

Tags: reactjs

I have tring to make a function to show progress when reading article.Problem is that this fucntion is contanly showing me 0 value.

```
   const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0)
   const onScroll = () => {
      const documentEl = document.documentElement

      const winScroll = documentEl.scrollTop
      const height = documentEl.scrollHeight - documentEl.clientHeight

      const scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100

      setScrollTop(scrolled)
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
   }, [])
```

Comment: I think your code is totally fine. You should share JSX which is the rendering part, or that would be better if you can share the whole component to fully understand your code.

Comment: Could you reproduce a problem in some codesanbox? I've tried your code it works just fine. See - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-814dvs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ok after commneting all my scss files its working

Comment: this error was coused by `body{hight:100%;}`  if someone knows why please tell me